# RegExp wildcard for numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to do a LOT of search and replaces in a lot of files. 
Right now I use notepad++ search/replace because it got regexp support.
But I cannot figure out how the regexp should look

Example from my file:

```
/* 25 */
data data data data 
data data data data data
/* 26 */
data data data data 
data data data data data
/* 27 */
data data data data 
data data data data data
```

I want to remove all the comments (the "/* number */" lines)

Any regexp scientists out there who can help? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Find: /\* \d+ \*/[\r\n]+
Replace: <blank>
```

The `\d` means "digit".

`\r` is the carriage return character and `\n` is the newline character. Together, they cover all line endings:

- Windows: `\r\n`
- Mac: `\r`
- *nix: `\n`

The quantified `+` means "one or more", so all together `[\r\n]+` covers line endings on all OS.

Comment: Works great, thanks @Bohemian!! .   Question, \r is replace but what is \n  and why the "+" outside [\r\n]+  `??

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `/\*[^*]\*/\R`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
/*      : begin comment
  [^*]+ : everything that is not * (1 or more times)
*/      : end comment
\R      : any kind of linebreak
```

If you want to remove comments that contain only digits, use:

```
/\*\s*\d+\s*\*/\R
```